# From a web app, I have to store a file in MS SQL 2008 DB. Do you recommend storing it as xml string or as a blob?

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

The web app has to let a user browse a csv file of around 100'000 lines.
We have to show the contents of the file on the screen so the user can see what has been loaded.
Then the user will perform some actions on the screen (e.g. add their details)
We need to store the file in database and associate it with the user record

The contents and the format of the file will change per user.
Therefore, I cannot create a static table in MS SQL DB for it.

Do you recommend loading this file as a blob in MS SQL 2008 DB or should I load the file, create a plain class (in C#) object that matches the file, serialise it and then store it as the xml file.  Later if user wants to see it, I can read the xml string from DB, deserialise it to the object, write logic that takes the object and creates a csv file?

Is there another approach?  Is storing as xml string better than storing as blob?

Comment: either as xml field type or as binary if you wish using FILESTREAM why not

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) data type in SQL Server 2008. Behind the scenes the actual file is stored on the file system but you get fully transactional access to it and the way it is actually stored is completely transparent.

Comment: oh didnt know about this.  can we control and audit it? and ensure user doesn't modify it etc

Comment: And if you can't, for some reason, use FILESTREAM (which I'd also recommend) then you should store your files in a separate linked by a foreign key in an additional FILE, so at least it keeps the row size small when you aren't dealing with then attachments.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, it's the same as a BLOB column. It's just that behind the scenes the file is actually stored on the file system instead of the database.

Comment: can we create a script that takes filestream and converts back to a csv file?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, of course. You will query your database to obtain the Stream and then based on its contents you will generate your CSV file.

Comment: @twilson, i didnt see a single benefit from your approach btw. by that you mean reduce length of columns? wont it slow down performance due to another join that needs to be made to get file? also what about use a sql select statement that doesn't include the file column!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov what are the disadvantages of using filestream other than the data cannot be viewed and we need to use C# to convert binary to appropriate format?

Comment: If you do a select statement that doesn't include the file column (when it exists in the same table) the row size will still be huge and therefore you won't be able to store as many rows per page, increasing IO ALL the time.  versus a separate table, stored in a separate physical file which will only incur the increased row size/IO when you actually look at the table.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, I don't understand what you mean by `we need to use C# to convert binary to appropriate format`. `Binary` is not a file format.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov if you read the article you sent me in your link above, you will notice that "FILESTREAM is implemented as a varbinary(max) column"

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, yes, of course. You will retrieve it as a `byte[]`. Depending on the format of your original file you could easily read from this array.